# How to check value of column exist or not in sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my code:

```
public boolean checkIDTraLoiBangID(int Id)
{
    boolean check = false;
    String query = "select IDTraLoi from BangCauHoi where ID=?";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, new String[] { "" + Id });
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    {
        check = true;
    }
    c.close();
    return check;
}
```

I'm trying to check value of `IDTraLoi` exist or not follow `where` clause. But, even in column `IDTraLoi` have no value this function still return `true`.

Somebody can help me please?
Thank you and sorry because my english...

Comment: What alternatives have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean with "no value"? NULL? Zero?

Comment: no value mean: NULL @CL.

Answer (score -1):

That code just checks whether a row exists.

To check the value in a column, you actually have to read the value:

```java
String query = "select IDTraLoi from BangCauHoi where ID=?";
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, new String[] { "" + Id });
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    check = !c.isNull(0);
}
```

Using a [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) makes the code simpler:

```java
String idTraLoi = DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(database,
        "select IDTraLoi from BangCauHoi where ID = " + Id, null);
check = idTraLoi != null;
```